# How to customize AspNet Identity 2.0 to generate only the identity tables I need?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am new to the Identity 2.0 module and I wanted to have control over what tables that get generated by the identity module in the database as I sometimes don't need all of them and even sometimes don't need most of the columns that get generated in each table. So, is there any way I can control the generated tables and columns?

Comment: The tables are those *Identity* and the selected providers need for their features. You *need* the tables, otherwise the features won't work. What features do you want to disable and why?

Comment: Besides a Notes field could easily be removed. The `PasswordHash` used to store password hashes is another story. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Let's say for example that I don't intend to use the claims table and the logins table. and let's say that I don't intend to implement functionality to lockout a user or check for phone verification. In that case I don't want the Identity parts that are related to claims and external logins and some of the columns in the Users table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables in SQL Server are cheap if not used. They don't really take any space and takes no effort to maintain. There is no point in removing empty tables/fields that were generated by a framework for you. That has been raised multiple times and I've not seen a good answer to that. Because what you want to do gives you absolutely ZERO benefits and adds a lot of work now and a lot of maintenance later down the line of your application.

However, if you insist on doing it, you'll need to start taking apart `IdentityDbContext` - you need to implement your own `DbContext` that only contains tables that you desire. Then you'll need to implement your own `IUserStorage` that can handle lack of tables. Here is a [starting point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) for learning how to implement a custom storage.

You can find a source code for identity, copy relevant storage code and remove bits that you don't want and add `NotSupportedException` for methods that you'll render useless.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. This will be a great help.